# How to open a .W2P (web2py) file on Ubuntu - rookie user

Tags: ubuntu, web2py

I am following a tutorial to learn my way around web2py.

When I pack the site and download it as a .w2p file, that filetype is not associated with any application.

Is there something I should have installed that I don't?  What would that be?

Answer (score 2):

The .w2p file is intended to be loaded via the web2py admin app, so typically you would just run web2py, go to the admin app, and upload the file -- the admin app will then handle unpacking the app into a folder in /web2py/applications/.

However, the .w2p file is just a .tar.gz file (i.e., the files have been packaged into a tar file and then compressed via gzip). So, you can also use the standard tools to uncompress and unpack -- see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file).

For more details, see the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#More-on-admin).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have w2p installed on your local machine, it sounds like you need to change the file association in your file manager. See this link [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289337/how-can-i-change-file-association-globally).

If you don't have web2py installed, there's a tutorial for installing it on Ubuntu [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Web2Py).